# ¿Como puedo generar una ID mediante las letras de un nombre?

Tags: javascript, html

Hola soy nuevo aprendiendo javascript quisiera saber como se podría generar un id mediante las letras de un nombre es un ejercicio que me puse.

por ejemplo ingresar el nombre: Juan Miguel

y que con ese nombre me genere un ID, que cada letra fuera un numero, la forma en que yo quise hacerlo no creo que sea la mas eficiente ¿estara bien o hay una forma mejor de hacerlo?, aqui esta lo que intente:

```js
        var boton = document.getElementById("boton");
        var id = "";

        boton.onclick = function () {
         

            var nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value.toUpperCase();;


                nombre.split("").forEach(function (n) {

                    switch (n) {
                    /*queria poner todas las letras*/
                    case "J":
                       id = id + "2";

                    case "A":
                        id = id + "1";
                }

                });
        
                console.log(id);
        }
```

```html
    <input type="text" name="" id="nombre">

    <input type="button" value="pulsar" id="boton">
```

Comment: el alfabeto español consta de 27 letras, lo que queres hacer es que cada letra sea un numero?

Comment: @Enzo si, no importa si una letra significara "20" o "27"

Comment: Puedes calcular un *hash* para la cadena. Revisa [Generate a Hash from string in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616461/generate-a-hash-from-string-in-javascript#7616484)

Comment: okay gracias lo vere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
// pasa de numero a caracter
function chr(i){
  return String.fromCharCode(i)
}
// pasa de caracter a numero
function ord(c){
  return c.charCodeAt(0);
}

console.log(`el numero 65 es: ${chr(65)}`);
console.log(`la letra J es: ${ord("J")}`);
```

Comment: Gracias creo que me servira esto, no sabia de esos metodos